# Refering to related object in ListView

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I am trying to create some kind of 'panel control'. I need to manage my objects directly from ListView. I'll show you transparent (I believe) schema what I'm trying to solve.

## Models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    prod_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

## Views

```
 class CategoryListView(ListView):
        model = Category

        def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
            context = super(CategoryListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
            # two class based forms created for models
            context['form_category'] = CategoryForm()
            context['form_product'] = ProductForm()
            return context

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form_category = CategoryForm(request.POST or None)
            if form_category.is_valid():
                new_category = form_category.save(commit=False)
                new_category.save()
                return redirect('category_list')
            return Http404
```

## templates

I use two modal window to open my forms which I added to my context views

```
<button>Modal btton opens product form</button>
{% for category in object_list %}
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3>{{ category.cat_name}}</h3>
                <button>Modal btn opens product form</button>               
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               <ul>
               {% for product in category.product_set.all %}
                  <li>
                    <p>{{ product.prod_name }}<p>
                    <span><a href="" class="btn btn-default">Delete</a></span>              

               {% endfor %}
               </ul>   
            </div> 
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="." method="POST">{%csrf_token%}
        {{ form_category.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="add category">
    </form>

    <form action="." method="POST">{%csrf_token%}
        {{ form_product.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="add product">
    </form>
```

For first form (CategoryForm) it's working fine because whole page refers to that (model = Category). Now is the question - how to create second object on that page. I can do this in DetailView using urls and parameter like slug, id or pk and after passing it as value but I want to do this from that page without moving to detail page.
Secondly I was thinking how to delete products from list but there is the same problem how to let django know that witch object I would like to remove.

Thanks.